# Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first function translates a div click into a custom checked/unchecked toggle. The second function translates a checkbox change into a check/uncheck event(this work fine ).

The problem is that when I use the first function to check/uncheck the box, the third function is not called. I am new to javascript, thanks.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
/*
  Progressive enhancement.  If javascript is enabled we change the body class.  Which in turn hides the checkboxes with css.
*/
$('body').attr("class","js");

/*
  Add toggle switch after each checkbox.  If checked, then toggle the switch.
*/
 $('.checkbox').after(function(){
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
     return "<a href='#' class='toggle checked' ref='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'></a>";

   }else{
     return "<a href='#' class='toggle' ref='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'></a>";

   }


 });

 /*
  When the toggle switch is clicked, check off / de-select the associated checkbox
 */
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   var checkboxID = $(this).attr("ref");
   var checkbox = $('#'+checkboxID);

   if (checkbox.is(":checked")) { 
     checkbox.removeAttr("checked");

   }else{
     checkbox.attr("checked","true");
   }
   $(this).toggleClass("checked");

   e.preventDefault();
});


});

$(document).ready(function(){

$(":checkbox").change(function(){

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {  $(el).layerSlider('start');
}else{ $(el).layerSlider('stop');}
});

 });
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5916151/1176601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an event to dynamic contents (in this case the dynamic anchor element)
you will have to use live or on function.

For jquery version earlier to 1.7 you will have to use Live function.

```
$('.toggle').live("click", function (e) {   
        var checkboxID = $(this).attr("ref");
        var checkbox = $('#' + checkboxID);

        if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
            checkbox.prop('checked', false);

        } else {
            checkbox.prop('checked', true);  //jQuery 1.6+
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

From jQuery 1.7+ Live is deprecated and from 1.9+ Live is removed.So, if you are using jQuery 1.9+ use On.

```
$('.toggle').on("click",function (e) {   
        var checkboxID = $(this).attr("ref");
        var checkbox = $('#' + checkboxID);

        if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
            checkbox.prop('checked',false);

        } else {
            checkbox.prop('checked', true);  //jQuery 1.6+
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

And also use prop function to check / uncheck the checkbox. (Prop is added from jQuery 1.6)

Comment: You don't have to use LIVE even for jquery < 1.7, it's still better to use delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Events change works fine now but the third function $(":checkbox").change(function() is not working , the function that check the event change  and execute the code that I need in this case .

Comment: @Gabriel Bora you can move the functionality of the third function logic inside $('.toggle').on("click", function (e) {}).  for example inside the function modify the logic to                                                                          if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
            checkbox.prop('checked', false);
            $(el).layerSlider('stop');
        } else {
            checkbox.prop('checked', true);
            $(el).layerSlider('start');
        }

Answer (score -2):

you need trigger change event on checkbox, not click

Comment: Could help me with an example how to use trigger change event on checkbox . Thanks